# Regular Expressions in SQL Server do not seem to work as usual

Tags: sql-server, regex

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn LIKE '[D][0-9]%'
```

matches a row with `MyColumn = 'D12345'` (obviously), but

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn LIKE '[D]?[0-9]*%'
```

doesn't. Why? And what can I do?

Comment: LIKE doesn't support full regex, just a super skinnied down pseudo-version of it. [List of acceptable wildcards here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by JNevill currently `LIKE` **doesn't** support full regex, moreover even **T-SQL doesn't support regexp**. To use Regular Expressions in SQL Server there are two approaches:

1) Call [User-Defined Function by using Common Language Run-time Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx)
 using [System.Text.RegularExpressions](https://weblogs.asp.net/farhank/creating-clr-sql-user-defined-function-to-validate-values-using-regular-expression). This approach is supproted since SQL Server 2005

2) In SQL Server 2016 and above call [Regular Expressions with the R Language](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4748/sql-server-2016-regular-expressions-with-the-r-language/) using `sp_execute_external_script`. In SQL Server 2017 you can call python scripts in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Use PatIndex

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE PATINDEX('%[a-z][0-9]%',ColumnName)>0
```